# Chaining output from one function to another?

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to compute effect sizes for an ANOVA using the `mes()` function of the `compute.es` package.
The `mes()`-function needs the means, SD and N of both groups. I can obatain these values using the `by(myDF$var1,myDF$var2, "stat.desc")` function. This workflow creates a table I have to manually copy & paste the values from the result of `by()` to the `mes()` function.

This is doable for a few anovas, but I need to do 50 additional anovas so I am looking for a method to programmatically chain these methods together. Does somebody have a good idea how to do that?
The `by()`-method can be changed at will, only the `mes()` method is important for me.

As a simply example:

```
library(compute.es)
library(pastecs)


v1 <- c(1,1,2,2)
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4)

df <- data.frame(v1,v2)

#I would execute this first, look for the values in the output and paste it to mes()
#I am using by() here because I knew it - there is almost certainly a better way...
print(by(df$v2, df$v1, stat.desc))

#I would like to insert these numbers automatically
print(mes(1.50,3.50,0.71,0.71 ,2,2))
```

Comment: A reproducible example would go a long way towards helping those who want to help here.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman You are absolutely correct - please excuse the omission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programatically do this by calling the appropriate functions:

```
mes(mean(df[,1]), mean(df[,2]), sd(df[,1]), sd(df[,2]), nrow(df), nrow(df))
```

Comment: Ugh, that is quite straightforward - I could slap myself because I did not think of it immidetately...

Comment: We all have those days

Answer (score 3):

Also note that `by` is a list and the individual elements can be access (@scott Ritchie's approach is much more streamlined):

```
out <- by(df$v2, df$v1, stat.desc)

mes(out[[1]][["mean"]], out[[2]][["mean"]], 
    out[[1]][["std.dev"]], out[[2]][["std.dev"]], 
    out[[1]][["nbr.val"]], out[[2]][["nbr.val"]])
```

Also no need for the explicit `print` call in R in most instances.

So the act of chaining is where you assign the output from `by` to an object (I used `out`).  Then use indexing to grab elements from that object.

Comment: Thank you!
I have accepted Scotts answer because it is the cleaner one, but I will try to remeber your solution for future reference.